# curl command behaves differently on Mac and Windows

Tags: r, libcurl

I have some R code that works on a Mac but someone else is trying to run it on Windows and it doesn't seem to work. The code I have been using is:

```
for(i in 1:length(SNPs.needproxies)){
       print(i)
       system(paste0("curl -k -X GET 'https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/ldproxy?var=",SNPs.needproxies[i],"&pop=MXL&r2_d=r2&token=",token,"' > ", dir,"out.",SNPs.needproxies[i],".txt"))
}
```

If I try to run this on Windows I get the error

> https not supported or disabled'.

We have narrowed done the problem in that it seems to be that single quotes should be replaced with double quotes in the address. However as this is within a `paste0()` function, it thinks this is something else so we thought escaping the double quotes with a backslash i.e.,
`\"https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/ldproxy?var=",SNPs.needproxies[i],"&pop=MXL&r2_d=r2&token=",token,"\"`

This kind of works in that it gives the output we want but it is supposed to print this to a file called something like dir/out.file.txt but it does not do this part.

The SNPs.needproxies is:

```
SNPs.needproxies <- c("rs709692","rs9659182","rs13064990","rs11130017","rs9832922" ,"rs36120363","rs4727815","rs7994762","rs72772387")
```

I have a token for the website but cannot share that but it is stored in the object called token.

Comment: Is it possible that not the result of `paste0()` differs but the behaviour of the system command shells?

Comment: @jogo thank you yes I did think this as well but also was unsure how to tackle this. I thought it might be paste0() because of the quotation issue, so would welcome advice either way

Comment: Does this work?  `u <- sprintf("https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/ldproxy?var=%s&pop=MXL&r2_d=r2&token=%s", "rs709692", token);
system2("curl", c("-k", "-X", "GET", u))`

Comment: Rather than use curl, why not use R’s builtin `download.file` function? You don’t seem to be using an curl-specific features, except maybe for `-k`, but that isn’t necessary here (the connection *is* secure — at least it is when accessing the URI without an API token; I’d be very surprised if supplying an API token changed that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. system() with curl -o option

After noting that curl on Windows requires the https address to be enclosed within double- instead of single-quotes, I would avoid the remaining piping issue altogether and use the `-o` option in curl to specify a file to write results to if you insist on writing the command out:

```
system(paste0("curl -k -X GET \"https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/ldproxy?var=", SNPs.needproxies[i], "&pop=MXL&r2_d=r2&token=", token, "\" -o out.", SNPs.needproxies[i], ".txt"))
```

## 2. curl_download()

Alternatively, R has a few curl-based packages that take care of all of these details such as `curl`:

```
library(curl)
url <- sprintf("https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/ldproxy?var=%s&pop=MXL&r2_d=r2&token=%s", SNPs.needproxies[i], token)
curl_download(url, sprintf("out.%s.txt", SNPs.needproxies[i]))
```

## 3. file.download()

You might also just use `file.download()` in this case as Konrad suggested:

```
url <- sprintf("https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/ldproxy?var=%s&pop=MXL&r2_d=r2&token=%s", SNPs.needproxies[i], token)
download.file(url, sprintf("out.%s.txt", SNPs.needproxies[i]))
```

## 4. GET()

You could also use `GET()` in from the `httr` library:

```
library(httr)
u <- "https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/ldproxy"
q <- list(var = SNPs.needproxies[i],
          pop = "MXL",
          r2_d = "r2",
          token = token)
f <- sprintf("out.%s.txt", SNPs.needproxies[i])
GET(url = u, query = q, write_disk(f))
```

## 5. LDproxy()

Note, there appears to be an R package specifically for connecting to this API [here](https://cran.r-project.org/package=LDlinkR). In your case the code would be:

```
library(LDlinkR)
LDproxy(snp = SNPs.needproxies[i],
        pop = "MXL", 
        r2d = "r2", 
        token = token, 
        file = sprintf("out.%s.txt", SNPs.needproxies[i]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing to do with `paste0()` itself but with the Windows version of `curl`, which *requires* the https address to be enclosed within *double-* instead of *single-quotes*.
Check [here](https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2019/08/06/windows-10-curl-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl-error/) for a complete break down of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The standard curl call in Windows is a wrapped version of PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod, which is why doing system calls will result in different results depending on whether you use Linux or Windows. I would recommend using the **httr** package in R, though it will require translating the calls.